# Sending AT Command to a USB-Connected GPRS Modem in C#

Tags: c#, command, usb, at-command

Can anyone give me a good direction or guide on how I can access a GPRS modem that is connected to a Usb Port. Should I make a USB driver for my program to send AT command to the modem? or Is like a router where in i can access it using an IP address? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If its recognised by windows as a modem then the required drivers should automatically present it as a serial port, just like any other modem & you can communicate with it using its port name & `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort`. If you want to access the AT/GSM command set there are libraries like [GSMComm](http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm).

Comment: you are right. there is a driver to make the usb recognized as serial port. do you think this url is a good start? http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Send_and_Read_SMS.aspx

Comment: It looks ok from the comments @ the bottom of the page, but the best way to tell is to try it

Comment: If you dont want to use readymade libraries then you can use DataReceived Event Handler of Serial port and develop your own custom driver for the GSM/GPRS.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, these devices mount themselves with a virtual serial port, that you can open, and send your commands to.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not useful to anymore, but when I plug-in my USB GPRS Modem, and install the software/drivers that came along with it, it created a virtual COM port.

Though it keeps changing after every reboot. Following code works for me.

```
var port = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort();
.
.
port.WriteLine("AT+CREG=2");
```