# Subcribe in read stream of 32feet (bluetooth client) in C#

Tags: c#, bluetooth, 32feet

i'm using **32feet** library to send AT commands to my phone (using **bluetooth**), i'm reading responses like this

```
peerStream.Read(sResponse, 0, sResponse.Length);
Console.WriteLine((System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(sResponse)));
```

but it useless, there is other way to use events and subcribe on some event to get responses in real time ?
Thanks

Comment: Connect the phone via USB, and try the solution in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937119/sending-at-command-to-a-usb-connected-gprs-modem-in-c-sharp or this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937119/sending-at-command-to-a-usb-connected-gprs-modem-in-c-sharp.  Search for [at-command][c#] on StackOverflow, and you will find other useful answers.

Comment: i'm using 32feet library not IO.Ports.SerialPort

Comment: Well it is only my opinion (and therefore just a comment, feel free to ignore :-)), but I personally would not use a 3rd party library for this task unless there is a big reason to do so.